# Can I replace a broken power antenna with a generic one?

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, antenna

I have a 1988 Accord. The power antenna is broken. The motor still works but the antenna doesn't raise or lower. I'm assuming this is due to the 'cable' in the antenna being broken or worn.

Just curious: would it be possible to replace this with any generic similar mast?

Comment: I've changed the headline question, as I think it distracts from the core question. As an aside, I haven't seen an external antenna in ages. Most cars here in the UK seem to have either a shark fin antenna or window patch

Comment: The fact it survived 35 years is pretty impressive. I don't know much work to replace it, but at worst you look at replacing the whole antenna assembly with a generic one.

Comment: Can pulling the antenna mast manually suffice? As I recall my motorized antenna from a '77 280-Z, whether its retracted or extended, the radio connection remains. Your choice to replace it altogether with a plain stick antenna and possibly open up a can of rust around the antenna base or manually extend the antenna enough for reception.

Answer (score 2):

A search on UK ebay for ["electric aerial"](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=electric%20aerial&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=electric%20aerial%20accord&_osacat=0&LH_PrefLoc=2) lists lots of replacement telescopic parts for electric aerials.  There are plenty of different looking ones, so I doubt you will find a generic one.

There are ones on ebay for Honda Accords, so maybe just dismantle yours and check that the suggested replacement part looks the same.

Example one that claims to be for an Accord -

[image]

I have replaced the telescopic part before on my Jaguar, it was a simple job to do.